# Conflicting types for method

Tags: c++, c

I'm getting this error that says "Conflicting type for method `compress`"

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

char* ptr = argv[1];
printf("%c\n", compress(ptr, 'j', 1));
}

const char* compress(char* ptr, char c, int i){
    return "Hi";
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is this C or C++? They are different languages with different rules. Please use only the tag that matches the language you are using. Also make sure the file name termination matches the language you intend to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attempted to use `compress` before it was declared.  As a result, the default function declaration of `int compress()` was assumed.  That implicit declaration doesn't match the actual definition.

Move `compress` above `main`.  That way the function is defined before it is used.

Also, in your call to `printf`, you use the `%c` format specifier which expects a `char` but you pass in a `char *`.  Change the format specifier to `%s` to match so that the entire string is printed.